# Is there a way to set one color in a JavaFX Image/ImageView to transparent?

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, transparency

I am looking for a way to set a background color of a PNG image to a transparent setting in my Java program. I want to do this because I am making a chess engine and want to highlight a tile on the board without drawing a new sprite for every highlighted tile. Is there another way? There doesn't seem to be any method or functionality in IntelliJ or within the Image/ImageView classes to allow for this.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nothing built in; you would just have to create a new `WritableImage` and copy the pixels over, replacing the ones with the background color with transparent pixels. Wouldn't it be better to have the underlying images with transparent backgrounds in the first place, and just place them over different colored backgrounds?

Comment: The issue is getting the transparent background in the first place - But I think I have found a solution. I'll use a full color image and adjust the transparency as a whole.

Thank you!

Comment: You can always just programmatically create transparent-background images as I suggested in the first comment and save those, then use them in your app. Not really sure what the problem is.